# CreateDatabase Delphi VCL

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Como criar o banco de dados automaticamente caso não exista, igual nos *app* do Delphi Android, mas quero fazer com o Delphi VCL. Quero que minha aplicação na primeira execução crie automaticamente o banco de dados onde vou rodar os *scripts* para gerar as tabelas.

Estou tentando seguinte código:

```
if NOT FileExists(Trim(sPath)) then
  conn.Params.Values['CreateDatabase']  := 'True'
Else
  conn.Params.Values['CreateDataBase']  := 'False';
```

Estou a usar o Delphi XE10 com Firebird e conecto com `FDConnection`.

Answer (score 2):

Enquanto isto garimpando no Delphi (tentativa e erro)  e no Google consegui resolver, além de atribuir 'True' para o CreateDatabase também atribui os outros params ai sim funcionou, Segue exemplo

```
    procedure Tdm.connBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
    var sPath: string;
    begin
       sPath := gsAppPath +'DB\MeuDB.fdb' ;
       FDConnection1.Params.Values['CreateDatabase'] := BoolToStr(not FileExists(Trim(sPath)),True);
       FDConnection1.Params.Values['Database']     := Trim(sPath);
       FDConnection1.Params.Values['DriverID']     := 'FB';
       FDConnection1.Params.Values['User_Name']    := 'SYSDBA';
       FDConnection1.Params.Values['Password']     := 'masterkey';
       FDConnection1.Params.Values['CharacterSet'] := 'WIN1252';
       FDConnection1.Params.Values['Dialect']      := '3';
    END;
```

Obrigado a Todos.

Answer (score 0):

Para Complementar a resposta acima 
Coloca uma componente de `TFDQuery`

```
FDQueryclose; 
FDQueryclose.sql.clear; 
FDQueryclose.sql.add (' create table teste('                ); 
FDQueryclose.sql.add ('    n_fields1    integer default 0, '); 
FDQueryclose.sql.add ('    n_fields2    integer default 0, '); 
FDQueryclose.sql.add ('    n_fields3    varchar(50))       '); 
FDQueryclose.ExecSQL;
```

Assim você Crias as tabelas.